# What is the property that nonlinear differential equations have that can make the solutions "more complicated" than linear differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I'll get straight to the point because I can't seem to be able to write a decent sentence today (sorry about that).

I know that the difference between a linear differential equation and a nonlinear differential equations is that the Linear differential equations have both the additive and homogeneity property and that the nonlinear differential equation doesn't.

What I want to know is how not having the property of linearity affects the set of solutions, like what can a nonlinear differential equations do to the set of solutions that a linear differential equation can't to make it "so complicated" ? (This question is a bit vague so don't hesitate to ask for clarification.)

Comment: non-linearity implies there are feedback of change of values to the base function. If feedback accumulates constructively, sooner or later the feedback can grow to a point which change the nature of base function qualitatively. Think about the outbreak of a pandemic, if inflection rate is low, the medial system can handle it and doesn't affect daily life. If inflection rate is high, all hell breaks lose.

Comment: Would you mind giving me a link where there is a somewhat rigorous definition of this idea ?